# Countable union of countable sets(ZF)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let ${{E_n}}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence
such that every $E_n$ is countable.

Let $g_n : \mathbb{N} \to E_n$ be a bijection for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $\alpha (n,k) = g_n(k)$

Let $A$ be the union of $E_n$'s.

Then $\alpha : \mathbb{N} × \mathbb{N} \to A$ is a surjective function.

Since $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is equipotent with $\mathbb{N}$, there exists a surjective function $f: \mathbb{N}\to A$.

Let $[n]$={$m\in \mathbb{N}$|$f(m)=f(n)$} for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Since $f$ is surjective, for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $[n]\ne \emptyset$.

Since $[n] \subset \mathbb{N}$, $[n]$ is well-ordered.

Let $l_n$ designate the least element of $[n]$.

Let $B=\{l_n \in \mathbb{N} | n\in \mathbb{N}\}$

Then $f_{[B]}$ : $B\to A$ is a bijection.

### Since $B\subset \mathbb{N}$, $B$ is at most countable. Since $A$ is infinite, $B$ is countable, hence $A$ is countable.

I don't know where i used AC in my argument. Help

Comment: *Let $g_n : \mathbb{N} \to E_n$ be a bijection for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$.* On this place you have **chosen** one element from the non-empty set of bijections between $\mathbb N$ and $E_n$, for each $n$.

Comment: You can pick $g_1$. You can pick $g_2$. You can pick $g_k$ for any fixed $k$. But if you want to create a single object $g$ that is a bijection $g_i$ for each natural $i$, you need infinitely many choices.

Comment: @Martin Okay. So, my argument makes sense when it is finite union of countable sets. Am i right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You used countable choice when you *chose* $g_n$.

It is true that for every countable set there is an injection from the said set into $\mathbb N$, however to choose exactly one for every set requires choice. If, however, you are *given* the injections then the union is in fact countable, since there is no need to choose bijections.

Note that if we only wish to take union over *finitely* many countable sets then we can choose finitely many injections and the argument follows. Similarly the finite product of countable sets is countable and non-empty, whereas infinite products could be empty even if all sets are finite.

See also the last part in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74676/axiom-of-choice-non-measurable-sets-countable-unions/74679#74679).

Comment: Then is 'Finite union of countable sets is countable' true in ZF?

Comment: Katlus: Yes, this is true because we *can* choose from finitely many sets.