# How can I prove like this exercise

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let we have $X=R$ the set of real numbers and $B_R$ is borel algebra and $2^X=P(X)$ 
How can I prove that $B_R$ is not equal to $P(X)$

Comment: In other words you need to show there are subsets of $\mathbb R$ that are not Borel sets.  I don't think that's particularly easy to do.  What level class are you taking?

Comment: There's an example on this wiki page of a set that's not Borel:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set#Non-Borel_sets

Comment: Have you searched the site for the many users who have asked exactly this  before?

Comment: If extending pre-measures is fair game, it would suffice to show that there doesn't exist a measure on $P(\mathbb{R})$ which assigns to each interval its length. There's a fairly simple proof for that.

Comment: @Jonathan: Not even a week ago, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209126/borel-sigma-algebra-not-containing-all-subsets-of-mathbbr and while I don't mind duplicates, searching for them is only part of the work I expect someone posting a question to put into the question. And here practically no work was put into the question.

Comment: @Jonathan: I found it by looking through the first three pages (set to 50 questions per page)  of the measure theory tag. Not an unreasonable effort.

Comment: @AsafKaragila can we agree the question at least deserves a reference to an answer? Even if OP didn't quite present his/her attempts at solving it?