# How to show that $C$ is countable?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $C=\{B_a:a\in A\}$ be a collection of piecewise disjoint measurable subsets of $[0,1]$ having positive Lebesgue measure.

How to show that $C$ is countable?

Comment: You may have a look at the end of this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74676/axiom-of-choice-non-measurable-sets-countable-unions/74679#74679

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $C_n := \{B\in C~\vert~ \lambda(B) \geq \frac{1}{n}\}$. Then $C$ is the union of all $C_n$ and $C_n$ is finite for each $n$ (the cardinality is bounded by $n$ to be precise).

Comment: why is $C_n$ finite?

Comment: what if there exist more than $n$ sets in $C_n$ ? Note that they are disjoint.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: $\displaystyle 1\geq \lambda(\bigcup C_n) = \sum_{B\in C_n} \lambda(B) \geq \sum _{B\in C_n}\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{n}|C_n|$

Comment: thanks but why is $\lambda(\cup C_n)\leq 1$?

Comment: because the union is a subset of [0,1]

Comment: thank you very much for the answer