# Countability of a sequence of natural numbers

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am trying to determine if that the set, $T$, of all eventually constant sequences of natural numbers is countable.

**My intuition:** The set $T$ is countable. . Let $T_j$ denote the set of sequences of natural numbers so that $t_i=t_j$ for all $i>j$.
If we can show that $\mathbb{N}^k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ is countable, then the union $$T=\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}}T_j$$ is countable as a countable union of countable sets is also countable.

Is my intuition correct?

Comment: Your intuition is correct.

Comment: To show that $\mathbb{N}^k$ is countable you might consider proving the general statement that the Cartesian product of two countable sets is countable, and applying induction.

Comment: [Assuming the Axiom of Choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935724/why-is-axiom-of-choice-required-for-the-proof-of-countable-union-of-countable-se) your intuition is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's prove that $|\mathbb{N}^2| = |\mathbb{N}|$. An easy way to do this is by using [Schröder-Cantor-Bernstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem). We easily see that $|\mathbb{N}| \leq |\mathbb{N}^2|$ by sending $n$ to $(n, 0)$. We also find an injection $|\mathbb{N}^2| \leq |\mathbb{N}|$ by sending $(a, b)$ to $2^a 3^b$. By induction we thus have that $|\mathbb{N}^n| = |\mathbb{N}|$ for each natural $n \geq 1$.

Now we can complete the argument based on your sketch.

A finite sequence of length $n$ is just an element of $\mathbb{N}^n$. An eventually constant sequence is a finite sequence with an infinite tail that has constant value $k \in \mathbb{N}$. So for each $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$ there is a set $S_{n,k}$ of sequences that after $n$ values just become the constant sequence with value $k$. Then
$$
|S_{n,k}| = |\mathbb{N}^n| = |\mathbb{N}|.
$$
We have
$$
T = \bigcup_{n,k \in \mathbb{N}} S_{n,k},
$$
which is a countable union of countable sets and hence countable.

---

As pointed out in the comments below your question, we generally need the axiom of choice (or a weak version of it) to prove that the countable union of countable sets is countable. This is because for each of the sets in the union we would have to *choose* a bijection. However, we can get around choice by explicitly constructing bijections $\mathbb{N}^n \to \mathbb{N}$. See for example the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function).

Edit: or see the excellent answer of String, describing an explicit bijection directly, showing that we do not need choice.

Comment: Thank you for the mention! Your answer is very informative regarding the axiom of choice, which might sometimes be the way to go.

Comment: I think I worked it out! I was wondering though, is it okay that we define our tuples $t_n\in T$ by $(t_1,t_2,t_3,....)$? Or must they start from $t_0$?

Comment: @StevenH That doesn't matter, it is only notation. If you'd want to start indexing at 5 or -580 you could do that as well (not recommended).

Comment: @MarkKamsma haha okay, awesome. I am having trouble showing this is injective. Consider the map $$f: T\rightarrow\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^+}\mathbb{N}^j.$$ If we define $f(t_1,t_2,t_3,...,t_j,t_k,t_k)=(t_1,t_2,...,t_j)$, we can take $T_x,T_y\in T$. How does $f(T_x)=f(T_y)\implies T_x=T_y$ and therefore injectivity?

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion works well, but I just felt tempted to propose the following bijection:
$$
f:T\longleftrightarrow\mathbb N
$$
given by:
$$
f(\{t_1,t_2,...,t_k,t_k,...\})=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{t_i-1}
$$
where $p_i$ denotes the $i^{th}$ prime number.

---

TonyK is completely correct in the comments. I will suggest a fix in a minute!

Comment: That doesn't work, for two reasons: (i) $f(\{t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_{k-1},1,1,1,\ldots\})$ is the same as $f(\{t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_{k-1},t_{k-1},t_{k-1},\ldots\})$; and (ii) integers whose last two prime exponents are equal won't appear in the range: e.g. $f^{-1}(2^33^55^5)$ doesn't exist, because it would be $\{4,6,6,6,6,\ldots\}$ but $f(\{4,6,6,6,6,\ldots\})$ is $2^33^5$. These are both fixable, but it gets rather messy.

Comment: @TonyK: You are right! Will fix it.

Comment: An injection is simpler: $\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{t_i}$.

Comment: @TonyK: Yes, I thought about that. A bijection is nice, though!